# Update to Laravel 8 in Laragon

Tags: laravel-8, laragon

I have no clue how to update my laravel in laragon.

I was told to go to Menu>quick add>laravel but its not an option.

[CLICK HERE TO SEE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW3wP.png)

Answer (score 3):

Update your Laragon PHP version to latest. Follow the instruction https://forum.laragon.org/topic/166/tutorial-how-to-add-another-php-version-php-7-4-updated.
Steps:

1. Download the latest PHP version from https://www.php.net/downloads.
2. Extract the zip to C:/laragon/bin/php/ and set the version of PHP from the laragon menu **Menu -> PHP -> version** and select the folder you just extracted.

After that, create new laravel project from the **Menu -> Quick App -> Laravel**.

Comment: Will this automatically upgrade Laravel version along with PHP version?

Comment: @s3c , yes it will. Newer projects will be of Laravel version 8.

Comment: Confirmed... TY